# Magento 1: when is the email added to the quote?

Tags: customer, magento-1, quote, sales, sales-quote

I noticed something interesting today.

I was working on a module that deals with the `sales_flat_quote` table.

I'm using this table to notify abandoned carts.

However, **one of the email in this table does not match any customer nor is present in any order.**

I never deleted any order nor customer so I'm wondering **at which point the email is added to the `sales_flat_quote` and how can I reproduce this behavior ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email address is added to the quote in conjunction with the billing address. On standard checkout, this is step 1 (or 2, after login/register) of the checkout process.

If a customer completes that step as a guest and abandons at any point thereafter (shipping address, shipping method, payment method, review), you would have the email stored on the quote and quote billing address, but nowhere else.